# How to save groovy output to pipeline variable

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, python, groovy

I have the below code in the jenkisn pipeline:

```
   stage ("amd_distribution_input_transformation"){
        steps{
            script{
                    amd_distribution_input_transformation url: params.DOMAIN_DESCRIPTOR_URL, secret: params.CERDENITAL_ID
                }
            }
        }
```

amd_distribution_input_transformation.groovy content:

```
def call(Map parameters)
{
    def CREDENITAL_ID = parameters.secret
    def DOMAIN_DESCRIPTOR_URL = parameters.url
    sh '''
        python amd_distribution_input_transformation.py
      '''
    }             
}
```

in the amd_distribution_input_transformation.py some code is running, and at the end, it returns object named 'artifacts_list'

my question is, how can I assign the return obect from groovy file to pipeline variable.
BTW, if it helps, I can write the output to json file from the python code (and here I'm stuck on how eventually assign that file to the pipeline variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `returnStdout` to true in the `sh()` command per the [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)?

You can then assign that output to a variable within your pipeline:

```
def artifactsList = sh(label: 'Running amd_distribution_input transformation', returnStdout: true, script: 'python amd_distribution_input_transformation.py')
```

and check what kind of object that variable is, and act on it accordinly

```
echo(artifactsList.getClass())
```

Comment: I clarified the question. Can  you have a look?